# SendGrid addContent php-function

Tags: php, html, function, email, sendgrid

I am working on a project where I am retrieving records from a database and storing them in a multidimensional array. Then I created a function 'printTable(array, int)' that creates an HTML table from the records. But since different tables need to be created for different users, I think a function would make the most sense. But if I write `$email->addContent("text/html", "<h1>Heading</h1><?php printTable(array, int) ?>")`, SendGrid  only sends the `<h1>` without the table.

Can someone help me further?

```
require_once '../phpFunctional/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php';
        $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
        $email->setFrom("asdf@asdf.com", "asdf");
        $email->setSubject("asdfasdf");
        //$email->addTo($email, "Empfaenger");
        $email->addTo("qwer@qwer.com", "ewer");
        $email->addContent("text/html", 
        "<h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <?php printTable($firmen, 3) ?>");
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('API-KEY');
        try {
            $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
            print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
            print_r($response->headers());
            print $response->body() . "\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
```

Comment: Try to echo the result of your function: `$email->addContent("text/html", "<h1>Heading</h1><?php echo printTable(array, int); ?>")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution, however it doesn't work that way either.